# python unicode: when written to file, writes in different format

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, mojibake

I am using Python 3.4, to write a unicode string to a file.
After the file is written, if I open and see, it is totally a different set of characters.

CODE:-

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    name = 'أبيض'
    name.encode("utf-8")
    f.write(name)
    f.close()    

f = open('test.txt','r')
for line in f.readlines():
    print(line)
```

OUTPUT:-

```
Ø£Ø¨ÙŠØ¶
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the codec to use when *reading* as well:

```
f = open('test.txt','r', encoding='utf8')
for line in f.readlines():
    print(line)
```

otherwise your system default is used; see the [`open()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> *encoding* is the name of the encoding used to decode or encode the file. This should only be used in text mode. The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever [`locale.getpreferredencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) returns), but any encoding supported by Python can be used.

Judging by the output you got, your system is using [Windows Codepage 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) as the default:

```
>>> 'أبيض'.encode('utf8').decode('cp1252')
'Ø£Ø¨ÙŠØ¶'
```

By using the wrong codec when reading, you created what is called a [*Mojibake*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

Note that the `name.encode('utf8')` line in your writing example is entirely redundant; the return value of that call is ignored, and it is the `f.write(name)` call that takes care of the actual encoding. The `f.close()` call is also entirely redundant, since the `with` statement already takes care of closing your file. The following would produce the correct output:

```
with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    name = 'أبيض'
    f.write(name)

with open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line)
```

Comment: Worked well, Thanks, and thanks for the nice explanation of what is actually happening..

Comment: @remisharoon: Just in case you didn't quite get what Martijn said about the line `name.encode("utf-8")` in your code... That call _doesn't_ modify `name`: it creates a new byte string object containing the utf-8 encoded version of `name`, but since you don't assign `name.encode("utf-8")` to anything that new string just gets trashed.